# About CPU usage function

Tags: vb.net, load, cpu

I'm trying to run this function that shows you the % CPU usage (not application, global)

```
Private Function USO_CPU() As Integer
    Dim obj_WMI As Object, obj_INFO_CPU As Object, Porcentaje As Integer

    obj_WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Processor")
    For Each obj_INFO_CPU In obj_WMI
        If obj_WMI.Count > 1 Then
            Porcentaje = Porcentaje + obj_INFO_CPU.LoadPercentage
        Else
            Porcentaje = obj_INFO_CPU.LoadPercentage
        End If
    Next

    If obj_WMI.Count > 1 Then
        Porcentaje = Porcentaje \ obj_WMI.Count
        obj_WMI = Nothing
        obj_INFO_CPU = Nothing
    End If

    USO_CPU = Porcentaje
    Exit Function

End Function
```

But I get this:

> Not found exception 'System.InvalidCastException' en Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Info: Conversion of 'DBNull' into 'Integer' not valid

I know that the error is caused by variable types, but I tried to set "Porcentaje" as String, Integer, etc and the error persists.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Turn on Option Strict and it wont compile

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning some null data that you need to convert to your datatype

```
 Dim loadPerc = If(Convert.IsDBNull(obj_INFO_CPU.LoadPercentage), 0, Convert.ToInt32(obj_INFO_CPU.LoadPercentage))
```

---- update -----

```
For Each obj_INFO_CPU In obj_WMI
    Dim loadPerc = If(Convert.IsDBNull(obj_INFO_CPU.LoadPercentage), 0, Convert.ToInt32(obj_INFO_CPU.LoadPercentage))

    If obj_WMI.Count > 1 Then
        Porcentaje = Porcentaje + loadPerc
    Else
        Porcentaje = loadPerc
    End If
Next
```